# C#: Default implementation for == and != operators for objects

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'd like to know what is default implementation for equality operatort (== and !=)

Is it?

```
public static bool operator ==(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    return obj1.Equals(obj2);
}
public static bool operator !=(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    return !obj1.Equals(obj2);
}
```

So I only need to override Equals method or do I need to override euality operators as well ?

Comment: I believe you should search SO, there are a lot of similar topics were discussed so going over few of them you'll got clean understanding of this

Comment: [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it's *not* that - by default, *references* are checked for equality. Operators such as `==` are *not* polymorphic and don't *call* anything polymorphic by default. So for example:

```
string x = "Hello";
string y = new String("Hello".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // True; uses overloaded operator

object a = x;
object b = y;
Console.WriteLine(a == b); // False; uses default implementation
```

You can't *override* equality operators, but you can *overload* them, as string does. Whether or not you *should* is a different matter. I think I *usually* would if I were overriding `Equals`, but not necessarily always.

Comment: Eric Lippert's [evil example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty.aspx): `object obj = ""; string str2 = String.Empty; Console.WriteLine(obj == str2); // sometimes true, sometimes false`

Comment: This is a very good answer and explains many other things along the way. This is where it differs from `Equal()` method. `Equal` method is a `virtual` method so `x.Equals(y)` would return `true` since it will be bound during runtime and runtime equivalent of that method is `string`s `Equal` method. But `==` can not be overridden but only `overloaded`, and which operator will be called is determined during compile-time, and parameter types will be used to determine which overload to get bound to. Thanks @JonSkeet.

Comment: While this example is right, the explanation is wrong.  The original question has nothing to do with polymorphism, overloading or overriding.  The default implementation of == calls ReferenceEquals() not Equals().

Comment: @Trade-IdeasPhilip: In what way does the original question have nothing to do with overriding when it asks: "So I only need to override Equals method"? And no, `==` doesn't call `ReferenceEquals` - it's the other way round.

Comment: He asked is the default implementation ... obj1.Equals(obj2) ...?  The answer is no, the default implementation is ... obj1.ReferenceEquals(obj2) ... or something very close to that.  That is why overriding Equals() is insufficient.

Comment: @Trade-IdeasPhilip: I answer the question about the implementation of `==` in the first sentence (that it compares references for equality), and then move on to talk about overloading which the OP also asks about. While I wouldn't say this is the best of my answers, nothing in the explanation is wrong IMO, and it certainly seemed to satisfy the OP and I'm happy enough. Of course, you're free to add your own answer if you think mine is so awful.

Answer (score 9):

The [C# language specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc), Section 7.9 covers the exact behavior of the built-in `==` operator. For example, when using `==` on reference-type values, the following section applies:

> **7.9.6 Reference type equality operators**
>
> The predefined reference type equality operators are:
>
> `bool operator ==(object x, object y);`
>   `bool operator !=(object x, object y);`
>
> The operators return the result of comparing the two references for equality or non-equality.
>
> Since the predefined reference type equality operators accept operands of type object, they apply to all types that do not declare applicable operator == and operator != members. Conversely, any applicable user-defined equality operators effectively hide the predefined reference type equality operators.
>
> [More details skipped...]

Note that "*comparing two references for equality*" does not mean "*the result of calling `obj1.Equals(obj2)`*". It means that both references must point to the same object (*reference equality*).

Comment: It's worth being aware that there are issues with the existing specifications for `==` and reference equality. It's a remarkably tricky problem to fix - we hope we've fixed it for the next release of the ECMA specification.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sounds interesting. Do you have a link with details?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. All the discussion is private, at least at the moment. (And a lot of it happened in person.) There end up being problems with implicit conversions, IIRC...

Answer (score 3):

By default, those operators test for equality of *reference*.