# Int32.Equals vs '==' operator

Tags: c#, operators

I looked around but no one seems to have asked this question before, so here it goes.

I'm working on a custom class that will have the `IEquatable` interface, and as such I'm making my own `Equals` method. Here's what it looks like:

```
public bool Equals(QueryFilter qfilter)
    {
        if (qfilter == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return ((this.Value.Equals(qfilter.Value)) && 
            (this.Name.Equals(qfilter.Name)) &&
            (this.Order == qfilter.Order));
    }
```

Where Value, Name and Order are fields of the QueryFilter class. Value and Name are `strings`, but Order is an `int`, and I was wondering if using the `==` operator is fine, or if I should go for the `Int32.Equals` method, to "match" how the other fields are making their comparisons? I checked the MSDN but it doesn't elaborate much, only saying that it's overloaded, but I'm not sure what that means in this situation. That the `==` will be the one at work always?

So in conclusion, which one is better? `Int32.Equals` or `==`? And when should I use each one?

Comment: You might want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345970/c-default-implementation-for-and-operators-for-objects

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, using the `==` operator is absolutely fine, so long as the *compile-time* type of `Order` is `int`.

If the compile-time type were `object` for example, then you'd be dealing with *boxed* `int` values and comparing those boxes with reference equality, which isn't what you're after. But so long as the compiler knows they're `int` values, it's fine.

Note that it's *also* fine to do this for `Name` and `Value` - again, assuming that the *compile-time* type of those properties is `string` (because then the compiler uses the overload provided by `string`. Then you can use the fact that `&&` is short-circuiting, get rid of unnecessary brackets, and get left with:

```
public  bool Equals(QueryFilter other)
{
    return other != null &&
           this.Value == other.Value &&
           this.Name == other.Name &&
           this.Order == other.Order;
}
```

... which I would certainly prefer to see.

This also handles the case where `Value` or `Name` is `null`, in an obvious way (null references are equal to each other and not equal to any non-null references). Your existing code would throw a `NullReferenceException` if it reached `this.Value.Equals` or `this.Name.Equals` for a null property value. (It may well be that you ensure that's never the case, but it's worth being aware of.)

You should also make sure that your hash code is consistent with equality, and override `Equals(object)` too.

Comment: I hadn't considered using operators for string comparison! And just like you said, I made sure that Name and Value are never meant to be null, but it's good to know this too; so thank you for the answer!