# .NET Delegate weird optimization

Tags: c#, equality

While browsing through the .NET Reference source I found the following piece of code, copied from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,196.

```
    public static Delegate Combine(Delegate a, Delegate b)
    {
        if ((Object)a == null) // cast to object for a more efficient test
            return b;

        return  a.CombineImpl(b);
    }
```

Notice the cast to `(Object)` which is weird. The reason this is done I'm assuming is not to use to use the `==` operator override of `Delegate` but the one from `Object`. However when browsing the code of `Object` I cannot find the definition of `==`.

Question is then:

`==` on `Object`, where is it defined, what's it behavior?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7346086/3181933) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator):

For reference types other than string, `==` returns `true` if its two operands **refer to the same object**.

```
// Reference equality: different objects, 
// same boxed value: False.
object s = 1;
object t = 1;
Console.WriteLine(s == t);
```